# Getting bad number in shell

Tags: ksh

Here is my code

```
bash-3.2$ cat nexus.ksh 
#!/usr/bin/ksh
LSEARCH=$(ldapsearch -p 389 -x -D "cn=xx" -w xxxx -b "ou=access,ou=nexus,ou=applications,o=xxx,c=xx" cn=$1 | grep -i uid=$2)
echo ldap search output is "${LSEARCH}"
if [ "$LSEARCH" -eq " "  ]; then
echo " User is not present in ACL group...Adding User to ACL group"
else
echo "User is present in ACL Group"
fi
```

output:

```
bash-3.2$ ./nexus.ksh acl.LINK_ODI_1 xxxx 
ldap search output is uniquemember: uid=xxx,ou=people,ou=access,ou=nexus,ou=applications,o=xxxx,c=
./nexus.ksh[4]: uniquemember: uid=xxx,ou=people,ou=access,ou=nexus,ou=applications,o=xxx,c=: bad number
User is present in ACL Group
```

can you tell where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$LSEARCH" -eq " "  ]; then
```

In Korn shell, the `-eq` operator is for *numeric* values, not strings. For strings, you should use `=`, as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ [ "pax diablo" -eq "pax diablo" ] && echo equal
ksh: [: pax diablo: arithmetic syntax error

pax$ [ "pax diablo" = "pax diablo" ] && echo equal
equal

pax$ [ 42 -eq 42 ] && echo equal
equal
```

---

> As an aside, you *may* want to look into using the return value from `ldapsearch` rather than trying to parse the output (which is more likely to change). One way to achieve this is to do the search, ignoring output, and check the return code:

```
ldapsearch whatever >/dev/null 2>&1
rc=$? ; [ $rc -ne 0 ] && echo ldapsearch failed with error $rc
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-eq` test compares numeric values. Since `$LSEARCH` has non-digit characters, it's causing your error.

Switch to `[ "$LSEARCH" = " " ]` or better yet `[ -n "$LSEARCH" ]` to test if `$LSEARCH` has nonzero length,

Handy reference for ksh conditional expressions: http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/man_ksh.html#condexp